# Why is `JSON.parse` not throwing exception?

Tags: ruby, json, rubygems

We have been using JSON.parse for a while now and we just updated to the latest version.

We are getting the following error.

Has the functionality been updated to return nil instead of throwing a ParserError?

```
2.3.0 :001 > gem 'json', '2.0.2'
 => true
2.3.0 :002 > require 'json'
 => true
2.3.0 :003 > JSON.parse("null")
 => nil
```

---

```
2.3.0 :001 > gem 'json', '1.8.3'
 => true
2.3.0 :003 > require 'json'
 => true
2.3.0 :004 > JSON.parse("null")
JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at 'null'
  from /Users/ryannealmes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
  from /Users/ryannealmes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
  from (irb):4
  from /Users/ryannealmes/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.0 :005 >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality has been updated to comply with the [JSON specification according to RFC 7159](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt), which says:

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
>   the following three literal names:
>
> ```
> false null true
> ```
>
> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are allowed.

So, `JSON.parse("null")` returning `nil` is expected functionality, which you can confirm by checking out the [tests for parsing single values](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/tests/json_parser_test.rb#L43).

Comment: This [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10143) states that the some `parse` expressions that conform to RFC 7159, but raise `JSON::ParserError:` errors. I confirmed that `JSON.parse('this is a string')`,  `JSON.parse(42)` and `JSON.parse(true)` all raise exceptions (for Ruby 2.3.0/JSON 2.0.2:), but `JSON.parse("null") #=> nil`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Check [the link to the test suite](https://github.com/flori/json/blob/master/tests/json_parser_test.rb#L43) for how to format the input as all values need to be passed in as a Ruby string.  Open up IRB and test the following: `JSON.parse('"this is a string"') => "This is a string"`, `JSON.parse('42') => 42`, `JSON.parse('true') => true`.

Comment: I understand.  Thanks.